# How to allow a forward slash etc. in angular route?

Tags: angular, routes

I would like to build a route that would capture every character coming after that. Let's say I have a route with a component serving the path

```
http://example.com/
```

and someone makes the following request to it:

```
http://example.com/http://www.google.com
```

I would like to capture the whole string after the route (i.e. the http://www.google.com). Is that somehow possible?

I'm really new with Angular (2>) and I couldn't make the *ActivatedRoute* return the string in the path...

All ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: try adding a encoded string there or use a hash to add it in the url etc.

Comment: I'd like it to work just the way I described. Without a hash or anything. So that the end user could type what ever she wanted to after the forward slash and I could get exactly that string in the component.

Comment: did you ever manage to get this working?

Comment: To be honest I stopped trying since it was just a proto of something. So no, I didn't.